# How to version an erlang project?

Tags: erlang, package, version, release, rebar

Is there any way to version/tag an erlang project?

So far I've been using git tags to state my version releases, and a custom field in my application's config (eg `{version, "0.0.1-alpha"}`). But is there any better way to achieve this?

I am using rebar, I've looked up but I couldn't find such a feature. I know rebar works perfect with git tags, but I would also like to state the version/release in a config that will accompany my project's files.

In extend I would like to include that "package-config" in my application.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions exist at several levels in Erlang:

- Erlang modules can be versioned using the `-vsn` attribute. For example, the top of a `mymodule.erl` file might be written as shown below:

  ```
  -module(mymodule).
  -vsn(1.0).
  ...
  ```

  If you don't specify `-vsn` the Erlang compiler generates one for you using the MD5 checksum of the module file's contents.
- Erlang applications are versioned in their `.app` files. For example, for an application named `myapp`, the top of its `myapp.app` might appear as shown below:

  ```
  {application,myapp,
      [{description,"My Favorite Application"},
      {vsn, "1.2.3"},
      ...
  ```
- Erlang releases can be versioned too, but how you do so depends on what tool(s) you use to generate releases. With [`reltool`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/reltool/) and `rebar` for example, you specify release versions in the `reltool.config` file. For example, for a release named `myrel` the top of its `reltool.config` might appear as shown below:

  ```
  {sys, [
         {lib_dirs, []},
         {erts, [{mod_cond, derived}, {app_file, strip}]},
         {app_file, strip},
         {rel, "myrel", "1.9",
      ...
  ```

  The "1.9" shown in the `{rel, "myrel", "1.9"` line is the release version number.

  Alternatively, with [`systools`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/systools.html), a `.script` file, which can be used to generate a `.boot` file to specify how to load and start an Erlang system, contains the tuple `{script, {ReleaseName, ReleaseVsn}, Actions}` where `ReleaseVsn` specifies the release version. For example, the top of `myrel.script` might look like this:

  ```
  {script,
   {"myrel","1.9"},
    [{preLoaded,
      [erl_prim_loader,erlang,erts_internal,init,otp_ring0,prim_eval,
       prim_file,prim_inet,prim_zip,zlib]},
     {progress,preloaded},
  ...
  ```

  You could write such a file yourself, or more sensibly generate one with `systools:make_script` from a [*release resource file*](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/rel.html), which generally has a `.rel` suffix and the top of which specifies a release version as shown below:

  ```
  {release, {RelName,Vsn}, {erts, EVsn},
  ...
  ```

  where `Vsn` is the release version and `EVsn` is the version of the Erlang Runtime System (erts) the release should use.

  With [`relx`](https://github.com/erlware/relx), release versions are specified much as they are for `.rel` files. See the [relx documentation](https://github.com/erlware/relx/wiki/configuration#releases) for details.

Erlang projects are therefore composed of a number of versioned entities, some of which might be under your control but others you might inherit via dependencies from other libraries/applications, including those from Erlang's standard libraries.

Comment: Cheers for that! Your 3rd bullet is exactly what I was looking for. I am using the rest, but as you mentioned, I was looking more for a project version release tag rather than an application-level (*.app.src) versioning.